# How to send Token to API in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, axios, token

Backend developer send me API like this To test it on poastman

```
http://app/channel_partner/patients/add?token=59bd1e3711ce73c150b68f3741df4363cf766a0e2fe54dcb5f804a08f3f0d525
```

But now How can I send token to API in react native I am sending like this but its Not working

```
      let url = URLs.addLeads;
        let options = {
          method: "POST",
          url: url,
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
```

Comment: you send it in the URL "search" ... i.e. the `?token=` is appended to the `http://app/channel_partner/patients/add` ... just like you wrote

Comment: sorry Bravo Can you explain me more or edit my code see my updated code

Comment: `url: url+'?token=......'`

Comment: let url = URLs.addLeads + `?token = ${token}`; = right ??

Comment: Oh, right, you changed your code ... yes, well, almost ... `let url = \`${URLs.addLeads}?token=${token}\`;` - NO SPACES around the `=`

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this with [axios](/questions/tagged/axios) so use the [`params`](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config#:%7E:text=params%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20ID%3A%2012345%0A%20%20%7D%2C) config option to safely add URL query parameters to your request

```js
const options = {
  url: URLs.addLeads,
  method: "POST",
  params: { token }
};
```

This will add a `token` query parameter with a correctly [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) value.

You don't need to change the headers; the Axios defaults already have you covered.